White screen in ElectronJS | MacOS
I'm trying to build an Electron JS application for MacOS. This is an old application that many customers have been using for about 7 years. Since then, no package in this application has been updated.
I was tasked with making small changes to this application and creating a new version of it.
The application works successfully in developer mode on my laptop, but I do the production build on another laptop, because I can’t build this application for the production build on my latest MacBook. After that, I copy the files to my main laptop to sign the applications manually.
I can't sign files on an old laptop with an operating system that's too old, and I can't build application in production mode on a new laptop with a version of MacOS that's too new. For this reason I use 2 laptops.
My problem is this:
When launching a new application on a client's computer, he sees a white screen.
We tested this application on different computers available in our office and it works well everywhere. However, on the client's laptop we get white screens. Why is this happening?
In the logs, I see the following: https://pastebin.com/raw/3vigwEXU
This error only occurs on the client's computer, so I assume that the white screen is related to it.
My package.json looks like this:
{
  "name": "myapplication",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "....",
  "productName": "MyApplication",
  "cordovaId": "org.cordova.quasar.app",
  "author": "...",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/quasar dev --mode electron -- --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/quasar build --mode electron"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Base64": "1.0.1",
    "ajv": "6.9.2",
    "archiver": "3.1.1",
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "bezier-js": "2.2.5",
    "chart.js": "2.7.2",
    "dotenv": "7.0.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.0.0",
    "electron-progressbar": "1.2.0",
    "exif-js": "2.3.0",
    "extract-zip": "1.6.7",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "jspdf": "1.4.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "2.3.4",
    "libphonenumber-js": "1.7.14",
    "md5": "2.2.1",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "moment": "2.22.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.21",
    "node-forge": "0.9.1",
    "papaparse": "4.6.3",
    "plotly.js": "1.39.4",
    "quasar-dotenv": "1.0.4",
    "rasterizehtml": "1.3.0",
    "regression": "2.0.1",
    "sort-json-array": "0.1.7",
    "utf8": "3.0.0",
    "vue-chartjs": "3.3.1",
    "vue-croppa": "1.3.6",
    "vue-i18n": "7.8.0",
    "vue-stripe-elements-plus": "0.2.9",
    "vuelidate": "0.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.1",
    "devtron": "1.4.0",
    "electron": "3.0.8",
    "electron-builder": "21.2.0",
    "electron-debug": "2.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "2.2.4",
    "electron-notarize": "0.2.1",
    "electron-packager": "13.1.0",
    "eslint": "4.18.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "12.1.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "4.3.0",
    "quasar-cli": "0.17.23",
    "strip-ansi": "=3.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.2.0",
    "npm": ">= 5.6.0",
    "yarn": ">= 1.6.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 10"
  ]
}

As you can see, we are using an old electron and a very old quasar framework.
Due to the versions being too old, I also have to sign the application manually:
codesign --deep --force --verify --entitlements "entitlements.xml" --verbose --strict -o runtime --sign "Developer ID Application: NAME" MyApplication.app

I do this for each file in the build and I receive a message stating that my application was successfully signed after uploading the application to the Apple server.
Entitlements:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

I'm guessing there's something wrong with entitlements. However, I don't understand why this works on our other computers. Can you please advise?
I also assume that we will have to update to the latest versions. However, this will take quite a lot of time and before starting such an update we must be sure that on our part we have done everything correctly.
Full crash error: https://pastebin.com/raw/3vigwEXU
